# PHPStorm / Intellij - Export / Import Database Settings

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

These two IDE's have a great database query engine that I rely on.  But I sometimes work on multiple machines.  I know that I can export and import IDE settings, but is there a way that I can export/import database settings from one machine to another?

I've looked and grepped through the file structure, but haven't found anything.  I am thinking it must be encrypted somewhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean ["Database" tool window](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/sql-support-and-database-tools/)? If so -- then it is saved in .idea subfolder (dataSources.ids/xml) if Data Source was created on Project level or in config\options\dataSources.ids/xml files (e.g. C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde60\config\options\ on Windows 7) if declared Globally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand you are talking about **[Database tool window](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/sql-support-and-database-tools/)**.

Such settings are saved in `dataSources.ids/.xml` pair of files. Location depends on how Data Source was declared:

- **Project level** -- in .idea subfolder next to other project settings
- **Globally** -- in `config\options\` folder (e.g. `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde60\config\options\` on Windows 7)

Comment: But how to declare datasources globally?

Comment: Ah, found it. In the `datasource properties` there is a `make global` or `move to project` button in the upper left